# Time base email aleart on open task

Tags: apex, workflow, triggercontext, trigger

Can anyone help....

I am trying to create a workflow action in Salesforce under the object 'Task'. I want a workflow to be in place that if a task is not complete by the due date then an email is sent to the user that the task is assigned to him and prompt to complete the task. If a further 7 days later the task is still not complete then I want an email to be sent again to the user.

I have tried to set this up but no Email Alert is not available for Task Workflow - can anyone help on a work around for this or offer some coding for me to put in place. I am a Salesforce Administrator so would love to learn!

Thanks
Russell

Answer (score 0):

Some workaround that might works:

1) Add new Task as Workflow action .This task will act as Email alert, make sure put Status as Completed and Due Date as Rule Trigger Date.

There other work around discussed here, you might want to look into.Don't forget to vote for the idea.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpAuAAK